# How to find source for a package?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I want to install dia for my ubuntu, and I encounter with this error:

```
txh18@lagrange:~$ sudo apt-get install dia-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package dia-common is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'dia-common' has no installation candidate
```

Is it a error with my sources?

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` first and try again. if you didn't modify the source list file, it should work.

Comment: It is a very strange behavior, I agree with HuStmpHrrr. I have ubuntu 12.04 and dia installed from official repository: as you can see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/dia-common) it is an included package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, Ubuntu isn't finding Dia in the repositories. You could try running `sudo apt-get update`, and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`, and try again. If that still does not work, then you can download the .deb package from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dia-installer/) or [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/dia), and [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/dia-common) and install it using the command `sudo dpkg -i PACKAGE_NAME.deb`. If dpkg reports an error due to dependency problems, you can run `sudo apt-get install -f` to download the missing dependencies and configure everything. (If that still reports an error, you'll have to sort out the dependencies yourself by following the examples on [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies))

Comment: thanks, I add deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe to my source.list, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:
you can install it from here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/dia-common/download

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sudo aptitude install dia` to install Dia, with all the dependencies met.

If you don't have `aptitude` installed, install it by using `sudo apt-get install aptitude`